# Python Numpy how to search for a row in a one dimensional array with multiple datatypes

Tags: python, numpy, search, rows

Very simply:

I have an array:

```
users = numpy.empty(10000, "U25, int16, int16, int16")

print(users)
[('', 0, 0, 0) ('Jim', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ..., ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0)
 ('', 0, 0, 0)]
```

I want to return the row with the string "Jim" in it aka row with index 2:

```
('Jim', 0, 0, 0)
```

What is the quickest way to do this?

Comment: Your array is one dimension, which mean you print users.shape will return (10000,)

Comment: What's the notion of a row in a one-dimensional array? And how do you know that the string `'Jim'` is contained in an uninitialized, empty array?

Comment: The test array will have to have a matching dtype.  `np.array(('Jim',0,0,0), dtype=users.dtype)`.

Comment: You can also search `users['f0']`, the 1d string dtype array.

Answer (score 0):

You have an ordinary 1-dimensional array of tuples. You can get the "row" just as with Python lists:

`users[1]`

```
In [22]: users = np.empty(10000, "U25, int16, int16, int16")

In [26]: users[1][0] = "Jim"

In [28]: users
Out[28]: 
array([('', 0, 0, 0), ('Jim', 0, 0, 0), ('', 0, 0, 0), ..., ('', 0, 0, 0),
       ('', 0, 0, 0), ('', 0, 0, 0)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U25'), ('f1', '<i2'), ('f2', '<i2'), ('f3', '<i2')])

In [29]: users[1]
Out[29]: ('Jim', 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: The `type` of `users[1]` is `np.void`, not `tuple`.  It displays as a tuple, and `users[1].tolist()` is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [501]: users = numpy.empty(10, "U25, int16, int16, int16")                             
In [503]: users['f0'][1]='Jim'
```

You can test a field as you would a regular 1d array:

```
In [504]: users['f0']=='Jim'                                                              
Out[504]: 
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
In [505]: np.where(_)                                                                     
Out[505]: (array([1]),)
```

But to test whole records you have to use a test array of the same dtype:

```
In [506]: test = np.array(('Jim',0,0,0),dtype=users.dtype)                                
In [507]: test                                                                            
Out[507]: 
array(('Jim', 0, 0, 0),
      dtype=[('f0', '<U25'), ('f1', '<i2'), ('f2', '<i2'), ('f3', '<i2')])
In [508]: users==test                                                                     
Out[508]: 
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

Elements (records) display as tuples, but aren't

```
In [511]: type(users[1])                                                                  
Out[511]: numpy.void
In [512]: type(users[1].tolist())                                                         
Out[512]: tuple
```

Testing them against tuples will give a FutureWarning.

Comment: Hi man, instead of doing users==test to get a array of bools, how would I return the correct row directly (by comparing the test array to users)

Comment: Actually don't worry figured this one out on my own: originalRow = users[(users[:]['f0'] == "Jim")]